# Naming Items in a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox populated by a List of a certain class. However when each element is added to the ListBox its name in the ListBox is its class hierarchy, but I want to be able to rename the items since it is supposed to be a Layer list for rendering teach Listbox item on a screen.

What attribute of the item does ListBox look for when choosing a name for each element? And how can I allow the user to rename items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be default, a `ListBox` will just call `ToString` on every object in its ItemsSource. For a class, this is just the namespace-qualified name unless `ToString` is overriden.

There are three ways to change what is displayed:

1. Override `ToString()`
2. Use the `DisplayMemberPath` property to bind to a property
3. Use a custom `ItemTemplate`

You could use a `TextBox` in your `ItemTemplate` to allow for rename, or another control (elsewhere on the page) that updates the backing property (therefore updating the bound object).